# Don't understand why this boolean comparison is failing

Tags: angular

Fairly new to angular, and not the most experienced javascript/typescript dev. Mostly smaller projects.

Currently have no idea why this comparison is failing.

```
if(data.success == true) {
      //do stuff
    }
```

where the data structure I'm getting is defined as

```
export class RegResponse {
  success : boolean;
  error : string;
  constructor(success: boolean, error: string){
    this.success = success;
    this.error = error;
  }
```

and
`console.log` of data.success is true.

`console.log(typeof(data.success))` is string (for some reason)?
but if I try a string comparison on the variable it declares throws an error for operations not applicable to booleans.

So I'm perplexed why this isn't working.

This as a work around works, but I don't understand why the obvious first comparison is failing.

```
if(data.success + '' === 'true') {
```

Comment: why don't just write `if(data.success)`?

Comment: @Kepotx if `data.sucess` is the string `"false”`, then it is a truthy value and the flow would go inside the condition. Don't do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you declare `success` as boolean, doesn't mean that your service will return you a boolean. If the endpoint returns a string, then it is a string.

Typescript is used for type definition, it's just a way to say "I expect a string here and a boolean there", but if the source is unknown then you have to do the check by yourself.

When you assign `data.success` you can do something like this:

```
data.success = response.success === 'true';
```

As a further solution, if you are using Angular 4+ you can implement a safe type-checking system just specifying the interface in the Http client.

You can read more in the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response):

```
getReg() {
  // it will return an Observable of RegResponse
  return this.http.get<RegResponse>(this.configUrl);
}
```

But it won't help you converting strings in booleans, this will just fail if you expect something and get something other!

Comment: I'm to in the mindset of typing being strictly enforced I guess. Thanks this makes sense.

Comment: @jdprepaprop the same code in a strictly typed programming language would have failed :) it's a pure type mismatch. I advise you to use the typed `HttpClient` to prevent these issues in the future

Comment: The conditional operator is not necessary: `data.success = response.success === 'true';`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes you are right, it was just to be clearer but I think I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

if "data.success" is only true, false, 'true' or 'false', you can try: `if(JSON.parse(data.success)) { //code }`